# Changing the selected image of the marked date on the Tapku calendar

Tags: objective-c, ios

Hi, I have gone through the web and many blogs But there seems no information about how to change the image of the marked date of the tapku calendar control.I have done some research on the code but could not completed the goal.

Write now i was able to change the backgournd image of the date tile .But when i do that the text for the date is gone any ideas??

I have changed the image on the `TKmonthView.m` file on the method

```
- (void) drawTileInRect:(CGRect)r day:(int)day mark:(BOOL)mark font:(UIFont*)f1 font2:(UIFont*)f2 method
```

please i need some help Here is my code

```
    if(mark){
    r.origin.y-=5;
    [[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:TKBUNDLE(@"TapkuLibrary.bundle/Images/calendar/Month Calendar Date Tile Gray.png")] drawInRect:r];

    r.size.height = 10;
    r.origin.y += 18;

    [@"•" drawInRect: r
            withFont: f2
       lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap 
           alignment: UITextAlignmentCenter];
}
```

Looks like guys nobody wants to talk about it .But I think i have come to a solution.The running code for my app looks like this.It just needs some testing and also for selection of the marked date i need some solution.I will look into it .My solution is following

```
    - (void) drawTileInRect:(CGRect)r day:(int)day mark:(BOOL)mark font:(UIFont*)f1 font2:(UIFont*)f2{

if (mark) {
    r.origin.y-=6.5;
    [[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:TKBUNDLE(@"TapkuLibrary.bundle/Images/calendar/Month Calendar Date Tile Gray.png")] drawInRect:r];
    r.origin.y+=6.5;
}

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",day];


r.size.height -= 2;
[str drawInRect: r
       withFont: f1
  lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap 
      alignment: UITextAlignmentCenter];

if(mark){
    r.origin.y-=6;
//      self.selectedImageView=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:TKBUNDLE(@"TapkuLibrary.bundle/Images/calendar/Month Calendar Date Tile Gray.png")];
    r.origin.y +=6;
    r.size.height = 10;
    r.origin.y += 18;

    [@"•" drawInRect: r
            withFont: f2
       lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap 
           alignment: UITextAlignmentCenter];

}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images are found at: `TapkuLibrary.bundle/Images/calendar/Month Calendar Today` or you could make the path point to one of your own images.

```
self.selectedImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:TKBUNDLE(@"TapkuLibrary.bundle/Images/calendar/Month Calendar Today Selected Tile.png")];
```

// you can use your own image

```
 UIImage *tile = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:TKBUNDLE(@"yourImage.png")];
```