# iphone TKCalendar selected date need dot with transparent image

Tags: iphone

iphone application i am using TKCalendar selected date shows dot by default so i need to display dot with transparent image on particular selected date. 
please help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242617/changing-the-selected-image-of-the-marked-date-on-the-tapku-calendar

Answer (score 1):

You may follow below steps to set custom image

1. **You have to right click the TapkuLibrary.bundle and select  show packet content**
2. **Now you can see folder as *Images* if you open that image folder you can see some folders**
3. **Among that folders you have to open the *calendar* folder**
4. **You can see so many images. now you can change images whatever you want**
5. **If you want to change only for selected date you have to change *Month Calendar Date Tile Selected.png* image alone.**

I think it may help you.

Comment: hello friend ,i was changing the image but it was not effecting in the simulator